# Authentication SAIO (swift all in one) using libCurl API in C++

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl, openstack, openstack-swift

I'm working to Open Stack in particular to Swift All in One (SAIO). I need to use C++ and libcurl for authentication.

Using curl via terminal I use this command (and it works);

> curl -v -H 'X-Auth-User: $SWIFTACCOUNT:$SWIFTUSER' -H 'X-Auth-Key: $SWIFTPASSWORD'

How can I run this command with libcurl in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append `--libcurl code.c` to your command line and you'll get a fine first template to start off from!

[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html) is the option to [curl_easy_setopt](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) you need.

See also [httpcustomheader.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpcustomheader.html) for a full libcurl example using custom HTTP headers.